# ADUser search: Get-ADUser and DirectorySearcher

Tags: powershell, active-directory, directorysearcher

With PowerShell, I'm trying to get an ADUser account with `Get-ADUser` with `LdapFilter` using the `employeeid` attribute. I'm using a GC server of the domain as the sourcing server for faster results. However, I'm not getting the matching ADUser account(s). However, I'm able to retrieve results using a `DirectorySearcher` object. Please refer to the tried code snippets below,

```
###

#1 DirectorySearcher

$empid = "123456"

$ldapcn = "GC://dc=mydomain,dc=net"

$ldapfilter = "(&(ObjectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)(employeeid=" + $empid + "))"

$objent = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($ldapcn)
$objsearch = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objsearch.SearchRoot = $objent
$objsearch.SearchScope = "subtree"
$objsearch.Filter = $ldapfilter
$objsearch.pagesize = 1000

$properties = "employeeid","givenname","sn","samaccountname"

$objsearch.propertiestoload.addrange($properties)
$results = $objsearch.Findall()

# Working
# $results contains matching user records

######################################################

#2 Get-ADUser

$empid = "123456"

$Server_AD_GC = (Get-ADDomainController -Server mydomain.net | select -exp hostname) + ":3268"
$ldapfilter = "(&(ObjectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)(employeeid=" + $empid + "))"

$results = Get-ADUser -LdapFilter $ldapfilter -Properties employeeid, givenname, sn, samaccountname -Server $Server_AD_GC

# NOT WORKING!
# $results DOES NOT CONTAIN matching user records
```

What am I missing here?! Any help would be highly appreciated.

---

### UPDATE 1

I just verified the Partial Attribute Set (PAS) with the code below and DO NOT SEE `employeeid` included in the list

```
$Domain = "mydomain.net"
# $schemaNamingContext =  "cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=mydomain,dc=net"
$schemaNamingContext = (Get-ADRootDSE -Server $Domain).SchemaNamingContext
Get-ADObject -SearchBase $schemaNamingContext -LDAPFilter "(isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet=TRUE)" -Properties ldapDisplayName | Select ldapDisplayName | sort ldapDisplayName
```

For more background, I'm running the 'DirectorySearcher' code block to search the source `mydomain.net` and running it from a `W2012R2` server joined to a trusted domain, say `mycaller.net`, which is from a different forest. Importantly, the calling trusted domain `mycaller.net`'s PAS *CONTAINS* `employeeid`. However, as already said `Get-ADUser` is unable to fetch the record(s).

Below is a screenshot of results observed with different environments,

[image: Get-ADuser-and-DirectorySearcher-Results]

Now, if not for a solution, I'd be glad if at least someone is able to reproduce this behavior.

**Query:**

1. In my example,

   `DirectorySearcher`'s `$ldapcn = "GC://DC=mydomain,DC=net"`

   vs

   `Get-ADUser`'s `$Server_AD_GC = (Get-ADDomainController -Server $Domain | select -exp hostname) + ":3268"`

   I expected both to work in a similar fashion. I see that I haven't specified a host for `DirectorySearcher` but have given one for `Get-ADUser`. Is this something to be looked into?

Comment: I'm surprised it works with `DirectorySearcher` in the first place, global catalog partitions don't replicate `employeeId` by default

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised it would work at all too. I did some testing, and I could never find an object by `employeeID` from a GC. Is your schema modified so that `employeeID` is replicated to the GC?

Comment: @Mathias and @Gabriel - Yes, this is the same query I had. But what I see is true. `DirectorySearcher` is returning matches but `Get-ADUser` did not find them.

Comment: Is this still the case?
Is the GC the same as the domain you are on? If you have a user not built on the specific DC you're using for `Get-AdUser` it might not find the user initially until they all sync.

Comment: @Riley - I get the point. As Mathias and Gabriel pointed out `employeeid` is not part of the PAS of the source `mydomain.net`. But how come the `DirectorySearcher` is able to find the user with `employeeid`. I've updated the post with more background info and some testing results.

Comment: How is the employee id created for each new user that comes into the active directory system?

Comment: The `employeeid` attribute is filled-in manually (from the HR records) when the user account is created in AD with ADUC.